# How can you calculate the total time taken for water to completely flow out of a container given the amount of water initially in the container?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, estimation, flow, fluid-statics

I'm doing an experiment on changing the amount of water in the container and seeing how the time is taken changes with it. The container has a little hole at the bottom where the water flows out from. I want to see if my recorded data matches up with the theory.

I'm not sure what other measurements you would need, but assume to know everything (eg. container hole radius, container dimensions)

Comment: Why don't you like the answer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/386895/theoretical-vs-experimental-flow-rate-of-fluid-coming-out-of-a-water-bottle-with) question?..

Comment: You should read about Toricelli's law. You will get some idea.